# JUnit library for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit

I am new to Kotlin.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Why IDE cannot see @Test?

Answer (score 0):

Understood. There are couple solutions how to add JUnit to your project here [JUnit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-testing-libraries.html)

But when I added it automatically it had "scope" Test and somehow it doesn't work. I changed to Compile and now it is fine[image]